# How to make ATI FirePro V4900 run 2560*1080 resolution?

Tags: graphics-card, resolution

I have a LG 29UM58 which runs at 2560*1080. My ATI FirePro V4900 only allows 1920*1080 on the ultrawide monitor. The ATI FirePro V4900 works fine with DELL 34 inch ultrawide with 3440*1440, but I don't understand why it cannot work with the 29 inch ultrawide with a lower resolution. I have tested the video card on two different computers, on both windows 7 and windows 10. I have tried the Custom Resolution Utility (CRU). I also tried the manual regedit method from [here](https://hardforum.com/threads/custom-resolutions-on-ati-amd-video-cards-non-edid-method.1605511/). None of those can make the 2560*1080 resolution on the LG monitor and it's always 1920*1080. I also tried to add custom resolution through AMD Control Center, but it says 2560*1080 is not compatible with the monitor.

The monitor works fine with other video cards. I just need to make it part of three-monitor solution through V4900.

Comment: What do you mean by 'doesn't work'. Does the driver give you an error, does the monitor show an error or goes dark without any display? Does the utility refuse to allow the resolution? Be more specific please.

Comment: What kind of cable (dvi, HDMI, etc) are you using to connect?

Comment: It is HDMI on the monitor and DVI on the video card. I use a HDMI to DVI cable.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I had exactly the same with my LG 34UM59 and FirePro V4900. 
My solution was to download the CRU program from [this site](https://www.monitortests.com/forum/Thread-Custom-Resolution-Utility-CRU?page=1). And add the 2560x1080 as follows.

[image: CRU Settings]